# how to prove continuity in multivariable functions?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$$\frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2},etc.,$$
in these multi-variable functions its easy to prove discontinuity by giving counterexamples but for proving continuity are there any tricks?

using $\epsilon$ definitions seems to so tougher in multivariable functions compared to single variable calculus

Comment: say at which point u can use epsilon definition also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're interested in continuity at the point of $ \left  ( 0,0 \right )$.

Use the squeeze theorem
$
 \left|   \frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2} \right| \le  \left|   \frac{x^3y}{2x^2y} \right| =  \frac{1}{2}\left|x  \right| \to 0 $ for  $ \left ( x,y \right) \to \left ( 0,0 \right) $